# flutter filter a list of objects with nested objects

Tags: flutter, dart, filter, filtering, riverpod

I have a `List<Country> countries`. each `Country` contains `List<City> cities` and some other fields about the country.
I have a Riverpod provider that holds a list of `Country`. In another provider I want to filter the list of `Country` by some conditions in such a way that a `Country` object might stay, but some of its `City`s will be removed.
I know how to filter the countries using `where(...)` but I'm not sure how to filter the nested `City`s.